# How do I add navigation menu on sidebar in TyPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to add a submenu on sidebar in some selected pages. The idea is like the following:

http://venicexplorer.com/explore-venice/annual-events/carnival-of-venice.html

How can I do that on TYPO3?

Thanks
Prasun

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello,
I am using Typo3 9.5. I've added the pages. Now I want subpages of the following page should be shown on the sidebar:
http://staging.venicexplorer.net/venice-culture/annual-events

Comment: Your question is very broad. Do you need help how to build a navigation menu for certain subpages in TYPO3 or how to position such a menu?

Comment: Hello, I need both. First I need the navigation for subpages only and secondly this navigation will be shown on subpages only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For buildung menus there a two ways.

1) The traditional way is by using typoscript and HMENU. Here you find the documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html

2) The alternative is to use MenuProcessors. Here you find the documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/MainMenuCreation/Index.html

To show only the subpages of a special page you can use a condition in your fluid template where you integrate your menu:

```
[PIDupinRootline = uid]

... here is your menu ...

[end]
```

The uid belongs to the page from which you want to display the subpages.

Comment: important: use `entryLevel = -2` to start the menu on the parent page to get all sibling pages. additionally I would recommend to add a further page-layout where an editor can select whether this menu (on any level or page) should be visible. if you use the fields `be_layout` and `be_layout_overlay` you even could simply select layouts for a whole sub page tree (depends on configuration).

Comment: Hi All,

Thanks for your valuable answer/suggestion. I can now successfully add the subpages on sidebar of selected pages. This is brilliant! But there is another small problem. When I tick the option "Page enabled in menus" then it is showing on both main menu as well as subpage navigation. But if I disable the option the page cannot be accessed via any menubar. Is there anyway where page can be accessed from subpage navigation and not from main navigation?

Here is the page I am talking about:
http://staging.venicexplorer.net/venice-culture/annual-events/regata-storica

Regards

Comment: You can us 'includeNotInMenu' in your submenu to show the pages that are not included in your main menu because of the checkbox 'Not in menu'.

Comment: Hi Robert,

Thanks for your quick help. This is now sorted.

Regards